# Xcode 4.6.2 app crashes on every second run

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

Xcode 4.6.2 seems quite buggy.

When I run a second time my *any* project I get SIGABRT crash within the first second. 
I completely removed Xcode and reinstalled, (yeah I try turn off and on again). 
Also I removed command line tools and simulators, but that didn’t help either.

Comment: Have you tried adding an exception breakpoint as [this one](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/add_exception_window.png)?

Comment: I tried, but to no avail. It still crash on the main thread while attach process.

Comment: In AppCode all works great. I'll use it until the next update xcode.

Comment: Xcode 4.6.2 updated some compiler / architecture stuff (maybe it was 4.6)... make sure to **clean** your project (CMD+SHIFT+K) before building with the new Xcode update.

Comment: Thanks, I know about clean. But it only help, if you clean every time before run.

Comment: did you find a solution by and chance? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Yes, now I have found :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

ok, I found a solution. Please open the menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, select Run YouAppName.app on the left, tab Info. Then choose GDB instead of LLDB in debugger field.

**UPD: In new Xcode 4.6.3 this bug has been fixed. So just update your Xcode.**

Comment: This was driving me nuts as well! I changed to GDB and it doesn't happen again. Wow.

Comment: Just started getting this issue today, I thought it was a 10.8.4 thing (just updated), but changing to GDB worked for me too. What a crock. (Edit: actually, it may be just a 10.8.4 thing: http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/)

Comment: Argh! Going back to a deprecated compiler, just to fix a (really painful) bug in the brand-new-state-of-the-art compiler is a big problem… But no choice, I'll have to do it.

Comment: Upvote for this as a solution, but are there any other options rather than switching to GDB? I was using the CMD., wait for 5 seconds but that got a bit boring

Answer (score 8):

Found another way to fix this without moving the debugger to GDB. I usually just re-run an app by pressing <kbd>⌘-R</kbd> while the app is running. Instead, kill the app from Xcode with <kbd>⌘-.</kbd>, wait 5 seconds and hit <kbd>⌘-R</kbd> to run it. Counting the 5 seconds by saying "I love Xcode" seems to help too.

**Edit:** This issue is [fixed in 4.6.3](https://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

Comment: Also can use ⌘-. and ⌘+shift+K (without wait 5 second press) and then ⌘-R on every second run

Comment: I think the time it takes to clean the build is just doing the same thing, making you wait a few seconds.

Comment: Yes, depending on on the size of project and the capacity of the computer.

Comment: Great, thanks! I found that "I love Xcode" wasn't long enough though, so I say "I'm in an abusive relationship with Xcode but I ain't gonna leave, I can change him" and that works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it has something to do with the latest update of iTunes (11.0.4), because I ran into the same issue after installing the update.

We might have to wait until Apple fixes this problem and go on with the above solutions which seem to work for me also.

Comment: It's just started happening for me after installing iTunes 11.0.4 (and OS X 10.8.4), too. Oh Apple...

Comment: Me too! The app, when running in simulator, crashes every equal time. It works every unequal time. So it works first time, crashes second, works third, crashes fourth and so on... I have not tried device yet this time. I am using CoreData in the project if that makes any difference. But I am not using any other things, it's a very light test app with no real features yet, and the simulator just chokes like this... bad vibes.