# iOS development. Must run twice to start the program?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I am using Xcode 4.6.2 When I am building the app, and run for the first time, it gives me
"Thread 1 signal SIGABRT". However, if i click run immediately, it runs without error.

How could i prevent this?

Comment: Enable NSZombie and then check.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of Xcode (currently 4.6.3). You may have encountered a bug that happens on Xcode 4.6.2 that runs on OS X 10.8.4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113036/xcode-4-6-2-app-crashes-on-every-second-run

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the `SIGABRT`.

Comment: Thank you guys. And sorry for not noticing that the question is already asked.